# How to refactor these identical logical structures?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I refactor the logical structure of these two functions?  As this logic grows in complexity, I don't want to keep both code sites in sync.  `IsValidDropTarget()` is used by dragging code to decide if you're hovering a valid drop target (should it highlight or not).  And `OnDrop()` happens when the card is dropped, where either the drop was invalid, or Card is played in a couple different flavors.
Seems like I should definitely be able to share this logic from one place, but I'm not seeing how since `IsValudDropTarget()` is asking a boolean question, and `OnDrop()` is performing a more complicated action.

```cs
    public bool IsValidDropTarget(Card card)
    {
        bool cardRequiresTarget = card.RequiresTarget();

        if (cardRequiresTarget && targetType == TargetType.None) {
            // Card requires a target but player didn't provide one.  Abort.
            return false;

        } else if (cardRequiresTarget && targetType == TargetType.Enemy) {
            // Card requires a target and player targeted an enemy.
            return true;

        } else if (! cardRequiresTarget) {
            // Target doesn't matter, play this card without a target.
            return true;

        } else {
            // Shouldn't get here.
            Debug.LogWarning("Unknown target conditions.  Card not played.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        GameObject droppedCard = eventData.pointerDrag;
        Card card = droppedCard.GetComponent<CardUI>().GetCard();

        bool cardRequiresTarget = card.RequiresTarget();

        if (cardRequiresTarget && targetType == TargetType.None) {
            // Card requires a target but player didn't provide one.  Abort.
            return;

        } else if (cardRequiresTarget && targetType == TargetType.Enemy) {
            // Card requires a target and player targeted an enemy.
            EnemyUI enemyUI = GetComponent<EnemyUI>();
            card.PlayCard(enemyUI.GetEnemy());

        } else if (! cardRequiresTarget) {
            // Target doesn't matter, play this card without a target.
            card.PlayCard();

        } else {
            // Shouldn't get here.
            Debug.LogWarning("Unknown target conditions.  Card not played.");
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: take the code that's equal, put it into a check-method, call the method...?

Comment: Where you call `IsValidDropTarget` method?

Comment: @Eldar `IsValidDropTarget()` is called within an `OnDrag()` event to decide if the object being hovered over should highlight or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example use an Enum that gives the state

```cs
[Flags]
public enum CardTargetState // or whatever
{
    NotPlayable = 0,
    Playable = 1,
    TargetEnemy = 2
    // add more values to your liking
}
```

and then introduce

```cs
CardTargetState GetTargetState(Card card)
{
    bool cardRequiresTarget = card.RequiresTarget();

    if (cardRequiresTarget && targetType == TargetType.None) {
        // Card requires a target but player didn't provide one.  Abort.
        return CardTargetState.NotPlayable;

    } else if (cardRequiresTarget && targetType == TargetType.Enemy) {
        // Card requires a target and player targeted an enemy.
        return CardTargetState.Playable | CardTargetState.TargetEnemy;

    } else if (! cardRequiresTarget) {
        // Target doesn't matter, play this card without a target.
        return CardTargetState.Playable;

    } else {
        // Shouldn't get here.
        Debug.LogWarning("Unknown target conditions.  Card not played.");
        return CardTargetState.NotPlayable;
    }
}
```

This would make your `IsValidDropTarget`

```cs
public bool IsValidDropTarget(Card card)
{
    return GetTargetState(card) & CardTargetState.Playable == CardTargetState.Playable;
}
```

and you could for example refactor `OnDrop` to

```cs
public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    GameObject droppedCard = eventData.pointerDrag;
    Card card = droppedCard.GetComponent<CardUI>().GetCard();

    var cardTargetState = GetTargetState(card);
    var dropAction = dropActionFactory.CreateDropAction(card, cardTargetState);
    dropAction.Execute();
}
```

`dropActionFactory.CreateDropAction` creates an action to execute for the current card and target state. In the case dropping is not possible, it creates a `NullObject` that implements the respective interface but does nothing and in case that there is any logic involved (as it is the case with `Playable` and `Playable | TargetEnemy`) it creates objects that implement the respective logic.

If you do not like the factory that creates the logic objects for you (although you should really like the idea ;) ), you could instead simply use an `if-else`

```cs
public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    GameObject droppedCard = eventData.pointerDrag;
    Card card = droppedCard.GetComponent<CardUI>().GetCard();

    var cardTargetState = GetTargetState(card);
    
    if (cardTargetState == CardTargetState.Playable)
    {
        card.PlayCard();
    }
    else if (cardTargetState == CardTargetState.Playable | CardTargetState.TargetEnemy)
    {
        EnemyUI enemyUI = GetComponent<EnemyUI>();
        card.PlayCard(enemyUI.GetEnemy());
    }
}
```

but this way, you'd probably end up with a massive `if-else` containing logic within the branches, which is detrimental to maintainability and readability. With the factory, you keep the decision *what* to do separate from *how* to do it.

Comment: When checking an `enum` you should rather use a `switch-case` instead of multiple `if - else if - else` blocks.

Comment: Nice, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  This is the one that I imagine scaling the best with future complexity.  Small bug, your bitwise checks have to be wrapped in parens to get the operator precedence right: `return (GetTargetState(card) & CardTargetState.Playable) == CardTargetState.Playable;`

Comment: I'm thinking I'll expand on this and have CardTargetState just be a class with IsPlayable() and GetTarget() methods.  It's a little confusing understanding the relationship between these flags and working out validity with bitwise operations.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply call the `IsValidDropTarget` method from the `OnDrop` method, right after you get the `card`:

```
public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    GameObject droppedCard = eventData.pointerDrag;
    Card card = droppedCard.GetComponent<CardUI>().GetCard();

    if (!IsValidDropTarget(Card card)) {
        return;
    }

    // rest of the code here
}
```

Having said that, in this particular use case, All of the code in the `IsValidDropTarget` method can be written using a single, simple line:

```
return !card.RequiresTarget() || targetType == TargetType.Enemy;
```

You only return true in two situations:
Either the card doesn't require a target, or the target is an enemy.
Any other situation you return false - so this is a more concise way of writing the same logic.

So here's how I would write it:

```
public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    GameObject droppedCard = eventData.pointerDrag;
    Card card = droppedCard.GetComponent<CardUI>().GetCard();

    if (!IsValidDropTarget(Card card)) {
        return;
    }

    // only two valid options here - either the target is an enemy or there's no target...
    if (card.RequiresTarget()) {
        EnemyUI enemyUI = GetComponent<EnemyUI>();
        card.PlayCard(enemyUI.GetEnemy());
    } 
    else 
    {
        card.PlayCard();
    }
}

public bool IsValidDropTarget(Card card)
{
    return !card.RequiresTarget() || targetType == TargetType.Enemy;
}
```

Comment: I can see how this is a reasonable refactor of what I currently have.  I don't like the compression of the `IsValidDropTarget()` logic to a single line though.  It works, but you really have to think about why it works, and there's no opportunity to explain the why of each condition with a comment.  But maybe more than that, as I add more targets and logic all of this would have to change.

Answer (score 0):

Since the logic of those methods is likely to grow - the idea is to encapsulate their logic within a new method with the following signature

```
private bool ValidateDrop(Card card, bool validateTaget)
```

The parameter `validateTarget` is a flag indicating whether we are only validating our target (call from `public bool IsValidDropTarget(Card card)`)

```
public bool IsValidDropTarget(Card card)
{
    return this.ValidateDrop(card,true);
}

public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    GameObject droppedCard = eventData.pointerDrag;
    Card card = droppedCard.GetComponent<CardUI>().GetCard();

    this.ValidateDrop(card,false);
}
```

The two methods are now very simple -

The logic is all encapsulated within our private method

```
private bool ValidateDrop(Card card, bool validateTaget)
{
     bool cardRequiresTarget = card.RequiresTarget();

    if (cardRequiresTarget && targetType == TargetType.None) 
    {
        // Card requires a target but player didn't provide one.  Abort.
         return false;
    } 
    else if (cardRequiresTarget && targetType == TargetType.Enemy) 
    {
        if (!validateTaget)
        {
            // Card requires a target and player targeted an enemy.
            EnemyUI enemyUI = GetComponent<EnemyUI>();
            card.PlayCard(enemyUI.GetEnemy());
        }

        return true;
    } 
    else if (!cardRequiresTarget) 
    {
        if (!validateTaget)
        {
            // Target doesn't matter, play this card without a target.
            card.PlayCard();
        }

        return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Shouldn't get here.
        Debug.LogWarning("Unknown target conditions.  Card not played.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: When checking an `enum` you should rather use a `switch-case` instead of multiple `if - else if - else` blocks.

Comment: This turns into a monster of nested conditionals, and Paul's feels cleaner architecturally, but this one is tempting because of how straight-forward it is.